# Sench Touch Json get response to string?

Tags: sencha-touch

I am working on sencha touch.  I am used it sample json url.  I got a successful result but I didn't get response value to string.

I am using code here:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
       url : 'http://webapps.figleaf.com/arch101/dataservices/mobile/beer.cfc?method=getExcuses',
   method: 'GET',
    params: {
        },
    success: function(response) {
        // this will give you the JSON       
        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', response.responseText); 

    },
    failure: function(response) {         
     Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Please try again.', response.responseText);
}
});
```

**I want to get the following response**

```
foo([
    {"EXCUSE":"I accidentally flushed my wallet down the toilet."},
    {"EXCUSE":"I ran out of water."},
    {"EXCUSE":"The Jets lost again"},
    {"EXCUSE":"I'm on a mission from God"},
    {"EXCUSE":"It was only one sheep..."},
    {"EXCUSE":"I think that I left my smartphone at your place"},
    {"EXCUSE":"My plants are all dying. I think they crave beer."},
    {"EXCUSE":"I need to listen to your Tito Puente albums."},
    {"EXCUSE":"I just found out that Darth Vader is Luke's father."},
    {"EXCUSE":"Sorry, I accidentally butt-dialed you. But since you have time to answer the phone, mind if I come over for a bit?"},
    {"EXCUSE":"I ran out of bacon and the stores are all out!"},
    {"EXCUSE":"Someone stole the cork from my lunch."},
    {"EXCUSE":"My girlfriend is preggers."},
    {"EXCUSE":"My girlfriend is preggers"},
    {"EXCUSE":"Yeast! If I don't get yeast within 30 minutes Ill suffer a brain aneurism."},
    {"EXCUSE":"I heard you had beer. Mind if I come over? I'm on my way over now, assuming you'll say yes. Thanks in advance!"},
    {"EXCUSE":"I heard you had beer. Mind if I come over? I'm on my way over now, assuming you'll say yes. Thanks in advance!"},
    {"EXCUSE":"You said tonight was our Battlestar Galactica marathon...?"},
    {"EXCUSE":"My parents are coming over."},
    {"EXCUSE":"I have plenty of bacon...but no beer. Can I come over?"},
    {"EXCUSE":"I left my iPhone 5 charger at my brothers and I don't have enough time to wait at the Apple store to get a new one."}
])
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm not completely clear. Do you get this array as string in your response?

Comment: Hi benda.i want to get just value.

Comment: Benda i want to display response value only.after that i am implement array and get details.But i can't get response value

Comment: so what is the content of response?

Comment: Hi Nicolas Grunfeld Please see that this link http://webapps.figleaf.com/arch101/dataservices/mobile/beer.cfc?method=getExcuses

Comment: just get response value and show it that's all .no need to parser and all

Comment: i am using response.responseText and jsonData.msg.But no use it

Comment: that's what Im thinking too-- what you get if just: success: function(response) {console.log(response)} ?

Comment: success:function(response) only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok use this:

```
success: function(response) {
    // this will give you the JSON       
    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', response[0].EXCUSE); 
},
```

response will be the array itself.

Comment: +100 thanks for benka.Thank you very much i got answer

Comment: hi benka if i want get all value means  i am used it          for(int i = 0;i<response.length;i++)
{
Ext.Msg.alert('Success', response[i].EXCUSE); 
}                                                              But this is mistake i know.but i am new for sencha can you help me

Comment: you can do `for (resp in response) {
 Ext.Msg.alert('Success', response[resp].EXCUSE);
 }`
this will iterate through all the elements

Comment: benka i got last value only.give me any solution

Comment: you got it all, but each alert pop-up is overwriting the previous one so you will only see the last one. You don't want to display as many pop-up alert messages as many `EXCUSE` item you have, do you?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: 'http://webapps.figleaf.com/arch101/dataservices/mobile/beer.cfc?method=getExcuses',
    method: 'get',

    success: function(response) {
        Ext.each(response, function(excuse) {
            console.log(excuse.EXCUSE);
        });
    },

    failure: function(response) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Please try again.', response.responseText);
    }
});
```